# Tizen Studio Debugger Message: Cannot launch application with GDBClient

Tags: gdb, tizen, tizen-studio

I am working on a [Hybrid App](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/community/tip-tech/packaging-hybrid-application?langredirect=1) (Web UI with Native Service) of API version 4.0 for my `Gear S3 Frontier`. After successful compilation of the App, In order to track the cause of application crash, when I launch it on **emulator W-4.0-circle-x86-preview in debug mode**, it gives an error message.

**Error Message:**

```
Cannot launch application with GDBClient.

Error in final launch sequence

Failed to execute MI command:

source G:\Computer Science\App Development\MyApp\GalaxyWatchApp\MyApp\Native Service\Debug\.gdbcommand

Error message from debugger back end:

G:\Computer Science\App Development\MyApp\GalaxyWatchApp\MyApp\Native Service\Debug\.gdbcommand:5: Error in sourced command file:\nG:Computer ScienceApp DevelopmentMyAppGalaxyWatchAppMyAppNative ServiceDebugMyAppservice: No such file or directory.
G:\Computer Science\App Development\MyApp\GalaxyWatchApp\MyApp\Native Service\Debug\.gdbcommand:5: Error in sourced command file:\nG:Computer ScienceApp DevelopmentMyAppGalaxyWatchAppMyAppNative ServiceDebugMyAppservice: No such file or directory.
```

**GDBCommand File Contents:**

```
set sysroot C:\Tizen\TizenStudio\tizen-studio\platforms\tizen-4.0\wearable\rootstraps\wearable-4.0-emulator.core
set debug-file-directory C:\Tizen\TizenStudio\tizen-studio\platforms\tizen-4.0\wearable\rootstraps\wearable-4.0-emulator.core\usr\lib\debug
set solib-search-path G:\Computer Science\App Development\MyApp\GalaxyWatchApp\MyApp\Native Service\Debug
dir C:\Tizen\TizenStudio\tizen-studio\platforms\tizen-4.0\wearable\rootstraps\wearable-4.0-emulator.core\usr\src\debug
file "G:\Computer Science\App Development\MyApp\GalaxyWatchApp\MyApp\Native Service\Debug\MyAppservice"
sharedlibrary
```

During the web search I found some of the `GDBClient` errors but couldn't find the solution to this one.

I've also tried setting the path of `GDB Debugger` to `i386-linux-gnueabi-gdb-7.8` and `GDB Command File` to the *absolute* path of .gdbcommand which should be run.

Comment: Can you please share the contents of the `.gdbcommand` file that is being used?

Comment: Right click on your project and go to `Debug As` -> `Debug Configurations...`, then delete the active debug configuration and again create new one. Please try this and check if it solves the issue

Comment: Even after deleting the previous configurations, it copied those configurations automatically. Where my **GDBDebugger Path is**: `C:\Tizen\TizenStudio\tizen-studio\tools\smart-build-interface/../i386-linux-gnueabi-gdb-7.8/bin/i386-linux-gnueabi-gdb.exe` and the **GDBCommand File Path** is the one which I mentioned in the question.

Comment: It seems like the problem lies with this line: `file "G:\Computer Science\App Development\MyApp\GalaxyWatchApp\MyApp\Native Service\Debug\MyAppservice"`

Comment: The paths are automatically read by the code ( for some reason, I've anonymized the path in my question which may lead to mismatching of paths in the question) e.g. the `MyAppservice` is basically the project name of the native service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the problem lies with this line: 
`file "G:\Computer Science\App Development\MyApp\GalaxyWatchApp\MyApp\Native Service\Debug\MyAppservice"`

Try to remove spaces from the directory name. Change `Computer Science` to something like `Computer_Science` and `App_Development` to `App_Development`. Then right-click on your project and go to `Debug As` -> `Debug Configurations...`, then delete the active debug configuration and again create new one.

You may also try by removing the whole line `file "G:\Computer Science\App Development\MyApp\GalaxyWatchApp\MyApp\Native Service\Debug\MyAppservice"` from the `.gdbcommand` file manually and check if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Your answer solves the problem posted in the question, as I checked it on a sample project `G:\SampleProject\Debug\.gdbcommand` but for me it's not working again when I moved my project to `G:\MyApp\GalaxyWatchApp\MyApp\Native_Service\Debug\.gdbcommand`.

Comment: Oops...then what is the new error this time?? same??

Comment: Yup, the same error exists when I change the path of my project, although the Debugger works **when I created a sample project for testing** but for my current project **the error is not resolved even after removing the spaces**

Comment: Like I said, the answer *generally* solves **the problem addressed in the question** but **it doesn't solve it in my scenario** :)